# Unable to create a radial gradient

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a button with a radial gradient, but everytime I load my app, it crashes.

mylayout.xml:

```
...

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheight"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton" />

...
```

mybutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">

            <gradient
                android:type="radial"
                android:startColor="@color/my_start_color"
                android:endColor="@color/my_end_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Below is the error log. I'm targeting Android SDK 22.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MyActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #324: Error
>   inflating class Button    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #324:
>   Error inflating class Button  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
>   com.my.app.ui.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:183)    at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:816)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:72)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:804)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
>     at com.my.app.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:1033)     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
>     ... 10 more Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-hdpi/mybutton.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02008a
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2482)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
>     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
>     at android.view.View.(View.java:3742)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:637)     at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:111)     at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:60)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:56)
>     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView

Answer (score 7):

You need a gradient radius:

```
<gradient
    android:type="radial"
    android:gradientRadius="40"
    android:startColor="@color/my_start_color"
    android:endColor="@color/my_end_color"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

Define bg_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mybutton" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/mybutton" />
</selector>
```

There you can also define a pressed state. That makes sense when you are using a button.

And this would be your mybutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:startColor="@color/my_start_color"
        android:endColor="@color/my_end_color"/>
</shape>
```

And at the end you have to set the bg_button to the background of your button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btnwidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btnheight"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button" />
```